# CSS - ::after pseudo element positioning and dimension issue

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have 2 images with transparent background and need to put one on top of each other with the same positioning:

- 1 spinning (underneath)
- 1 fixed (above)

I need to have the whole image composition to be centered and to have its size adjusted depending on the window size.

I used an `::after` pseudo element for the fixed one but couldn’t get its position and size to follow the spinning one.

I suppose the `background-size` property should be involved but didn’t manage to use it properly.

Would appreciate any advice, even if it involves going with a totally different approach than the `::after` pseudo class.

Many thanks.

```css
body{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #000;
   text-align: center;
   color: #fff;
  }
  .main-container{
   background-color: #00f;
   width: 50%;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .engine-container{
  }
  .engine-complete{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0 auto; 
  }
  .engine-complete::after{
   content: ""; 
   position: absolute;
   width: 191px;
   height: 192px;
   top: 1px;
   left: 0;
   background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/jOqNma/engine1_crpd.png); 
  }
  .engine-rotating{
   width: 50%;
   height: auto;   
  }
  .spin {
    animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-play-state: running;
  }
  @keyframes spin {
    from {
      transform:rotate(360deg);
    }

    to {
       transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <h1>spinning engine</h1>
  <div class="engine-container">
   <div class="engine-complete">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nwOKXF/engine1.png" width=191 height=192 class="engine-rotating spin"/>  
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

**EDIT:** Instead of setting the image as a background using the `::after` pseudo-class, I added the fixed image into the html. I also eliminated one of your containers.

I centred the animated image using `text-align:center` and centred the fixed image using `position: absolute`

I set both images to 30% width relative their parent `.engine-container`

The fixed image has a higher z-index than the animated image so that it always appears over it. The images also change size accordingly, relative to window size.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-container {
  background-color: #00f;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.engine-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.engine-rotating,
.engine-fixed {
  width: 30%;
}

.engine-fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  z-index: 5000;
}

.spin {
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <h1>spinning engine</h1>
  <div class="engine-container">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nwOKXF/engine1.png" class="engine-rotating spin" />
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jOqNma/engine1_crpd.png" class="engine-fixed" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
Heres what I came up with:

A similar effect using `::after`. I was able to achieve this by inserting the image url into the `content:` rule, rather than setting a background image.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-container {
  background-color: #00f;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.engine-container{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;

}

.engine-rotating{
}

.engine-container::after{
  content: url('https://image.ibb.co/jOqNma/engine1_crpd.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  z-index: 5000;
}

.spin{
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes spin{
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <h1>spinning engine</h1>
  <div class="engine-container">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nwOKXF/engine1.png" class="engine-rotating spin" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Jcode, this fixed my issue and is a good solution indeed! Still wondering if it would be achievable with an `::after` pseudo class though, do you think so?

Comment: @Surreal I added an alternate solution above!

Comment: thanks but the alternative solution looks it misses the images size to adjust depending on the window size. I encountered the same issue when trying to use the `::after` pseudo class

Answer (score 0):

Set `position` for `.engine-complete::after` to `relative`

```
.engine-complete::after {position: relative}
```

```css
body{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #000;
   text-align: center;
   color: #fff;
  }
  .main-container{
   background-color: #00f;
   width: 50%;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .engine-container{
  }
  .engine-complete{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0 auto; 
  }
  .engine-complete::after{
   content: ""; 
   position: relative; /* this was changed */
   width: 191px;
   height: 192px;
   top: 1px;
   left: 0;
   background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/jOqNma/engine1_crpd.png); 
  }
  .engine-rotating{
   width: 50%;
   height: auto;   
  }
  .spin {
    animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-play-state: running;
  }
  @keyframes spin {
    from {
      transform:rotate(360deg);
    }

    to {
       transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <h1>spinning engine</h1>
  <div class="engine-container">
   <div class="engine-complete">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nwOKXF/engine1.png" width=191 height=192 class="engine-rotating spin"/>  
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the issue as it completely hides the fixed image.